# Update a Table when Changing Data in Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a training Database in Access 2010 that I am creating.  I have `courseindex` which is the table that has course titles and the course required frequency.  I also have `trainingcompleted` which is the table that contains all training my employees have completed.  The form `training` contains employee data and all training each employee has completed.

On the form, the training completed is selected from a combo box, linked to `courseindex`.  When I update the combo box, I would like to auto update the next due field in the table `trainingcompleted`.

Once completed I should be able to generate a report, where the user enters a date range and it will tell me who is due for training within that time frame.  I have the the forms, tables, and reports set up.  I can enter the next due data in manually each time I update a record, but I would rather tha data be updated automatically, since the frequency for each training will never change.

I'm learning Access as I go.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the update next due field a constant?  Like will it ALWAYS be 30 days?  Or will it be based on the course/training they take?

Comment: It will be based on the course taken.  I have a list of 50 courses; some are yearly, some bi-annually, some are only required upon hire.

Comment: Ok, and do you update then from a form or directly in the tables?

Comment: I update from the form

Comment: Since you already know the dates needed, then I would add a line of code with `DateAdd()` http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx that would update a field based on the next training.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think that is going to help me though.  It looks like this would only work if every training has the same schedule/frequency.

Comment: Not if you use a in integer variable instead of a static number